# Could not find a matching loader for the scheme "file+ini ", protocol "wsgi" when running a Pyramid project in PyCharm (Professional version)

Tags: python, pycharm, uwsgi, wsgi, pyramid

I got an error about 'could not find a matching loader for the scheme' when I want to run my Pyramid web app in PyCharm based on Pyramid server. However, if I directly run pserve myapp.ini in terminal, it can launch my web app locally. I have edit the configuration in PyCharm: the config file is pointed to myapp.ini and the Python interpreter is pointed to python in the virtual environment.

*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/pycharm_load_entry_point.py", line 12, in 
sys.exit(f())
File "/Users/simon/Documents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 34, in main
return command.run()
File "/Users/simon/Documents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 193, in run
loader = self._get_config_loader(config_uri)
File "/Users/simon/Documents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/common.py", line 23, in get_config_loader
return plaster.get_loader(config_uri, protocols=['wsgi'])
File "/Users/simon/Documents/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plaster/loaders.py", line 109, in get_loader
raise LoaderNotFound(requested_scheme, protocols=protocols)
plaster.exceptions.LoaderNotFound: Could not find a matching loader for the scheme "file+ini ", protocol "wsgi".*

*Process finished with exit code 1*

Though I go to the official website about plaster and WSGI, I still cannot figure it out.

Do anyone have any suggestion or have any similar problem when configuring Pyramid web app in PyCharm?

Thanks.

Comment: From https://groups.google.com/g/pylons-discuss/c/H3zDRsw8Ykg "Please include a screenshot of your project's run configuration." and "What is the value for your Working Directory in the run configuration?"

Comment: @StevePiercy Yes, it the Working Directory problem in the run configuration. When it is provided, it works. Thanks.

Comment: would you please accept my answer below as the solution? Thank you!

Comment: Sure. It is done and accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have entered all the required values in a Run/Debug Configuration.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html#create-permanent

> ### Create a run/debug configuration from a template
>
> 1. Open the Run/Debug Configuration dialog in one of the following ways:
>
>    - Select *Run | Edit Configurations* from the main menu.
>    - With the Navigation bar visible (*View | Appearance | Navigation Bar*), choose *Edit Configurations* from the run/debug configuration selector.
>    - Press `⌃⌥R` and then press `0`.
> 2. In the *Run/Debug Configuration* dialog, click *+* on the toolbar or press `⌘N`. The list shows the run/debug configuration templates.
>
>    Select the desired template. If you are not sure which template to choose, refer to Run/debug configurations dialog for more information on particular templates.
>
>    [image: Run/Debug Configurations]
> 3. Specify the run/debug configuration name in the *Name* field. This name will be shown in the list of the available run/debug configurations.
> 4. [Omitted]
> 5. Set the run/debug configuration parameters.

The required parameters for a Pyramid project`*` include **Name**, **Config file**, **Project**, **Python interpreter**, and **Working directory**. You needed to add **Working directory**.

`*` [I don't know why they call it a "Pyramid server"](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-50696). Pyramid is a web framework, not a server. Waitress and Werkzeug are servers.